# Try 3d plotting probability density function for multivariate normal distribution

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have this code adapted from here:https://scipython.com/blog/visualizing-the-bivariate-gaussian-distribution/
to work with my data.

My data

```
hour    Cost
20  58.00
20  336.00
20  34.50
20  106.50
20  118.00
...
11  198.36
11  276.00
11  40.00
11  308.00
11  140.00
11  72.00
11  116.50
11  290.00
11  266.00
11  66.00
11  100.00
11  79.00
11  106.00
11  160.00
```

My Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal


dataset=df[['hour','Cost']]

X = dataset.hour.values
Y = dataset.Cost.values

X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
N = len(X)

def estimateGaussian(dataset):
    mu = np.mean(dataset, axis=0)
    sigma = np.cov(dataset.T)
    return mu, sigma


mu, Sigma = estimateGaussian(dataset)

pos = np.empty(X.shape + (2,))
pos[:, :, 0] = X
pos[:, :, 1] = Y

F = multivariate_normal(pos, mu, Sigma)
Z = F.pdf(pos)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=3, cstride=3, linewidth=1, antialiased=True,
                cmap=cm.viridis)

cset = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, zdir='z', offset=-0.15, cmap=cm.viridis)

# Adjust the limits, ticks and view angle
ax.set_zlim(-0.15,0.2)
ax.set_zticks(np.linspace(0,0.2,5))
ax.view_init(27, 90)

plt.show()
```

Suppose hour and cost any random vectors

- How do I fix this error?

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_multivariate.py in __init__(self, mean, cov, allow_singular, seed, maxpts, abseps, releps)
    725         self._dist = multivariate_normal_gen(seed)
    726         self.dim, self.mean, self.cov = self._dist._process_parameters(
--> 727                                                             None, mean, cov)
    728         self.cov_info = _PSD(self.cov, allow_singular=allow_singular)
    729         if not maxpts:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_multivariate.py in _process_parameters(self, dim, mean, cov)
    397 
    398         if mean.ndim != 1 or mean.shape[0] != dim:
--> 399             raise ValueError("Array 'mean' must be a vector of length %d." % dim)
    400         if cov.ndim == 0:
    401             cov = cov * np.eye(dim)

ValueError: Array 'mean' must be a vector of length 173873952.
```

- How do I know probability for any pair of (hour,Cost) in my data and visualize them?

Sorry for mistakes I am not a native speaker in English.

So my question stayed for a while without an answer,i took @ImportanceOfBeingErnest advice to simplify the example and make it verifiable example:

This is a simple example:

```
time=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
cost=[4,5,3,4,8,9]
var_matrix=np.array([time,cost]).T
mean = np.mean(var_matrix,axis=0)
sigma = np.cov(var_matrix.T)
y = multivariate_normal.pdf(var_matrix, mean=mean, cov=sigma,allow_singular=True)
```

- How do plot 3d graph show (cost,time) and probability density value for pairs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show a [mcve], i.e. a runnable code inside your question.

Comment: Looking at your data, the use of `np.meshgrid` is non-sensical here. The error itself comes from wrong input to `multivariate_normal`, see its [documenation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html)  for how to use it.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  Thanks for reply, I've edited my question and added simple example without  np.meshgrid function to discuss about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly apply the example given in the [`multivariate_normal` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

time=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
cost=[4,5,3,4,8,9]

var_matrix=np.array([time,cost]).T
mean = np.mean(var_matrix,axis=0)
sigma = np.cov(var_matrix.T)
dist = multivariate_normal(mean, cov=sigma)

x, y = np.mgrid[1:6.02:.05, 3:9.02:.05]
pos = np.empty(x.shape + (2,))
pos[:, :, 0] = x; pos[:, :, 1] = y

z = dist.pdf(pos)

plt.contourf(x,y,z)
plt.show()
```

[image]